# How To Apply A Sequence of Shortcut Keys in MS Word

Tags: macos, ms-word

I am using MS word 365 on Mac. I have a line like

```
123 ibsom sic  asdfas
sdfsdfsdf asdf
sdfsdf asdfasdf

124 sdfasdf  asdfasdf
asdfasdf  asdfasdf
```

I need to center the numbers and move them up!

```
      123 
ibsom sic  asdfas
sdfsdfsdf asdf
sdfsdf asdfasdf

      124 
sdfasdf  asdfasdf
asdfasdf  asdfasdf
```

I created a style to make numbers bold and center them ( assigned F3 in MS word for that). I also used the regex (^#^#^# to find 3 digit numbers, admit don't know how do this for a general integer). There for I need to repeatedly apply a sequence of shortcut keys:

1. cmd+G ( next find)
2. left Arrow
3. Enter
4. up arrow
5. F3 ( apply the MS WORD style)

How can I do this, please? I used macros but I had not success. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
CS

Comment: Applying raw keystrokes is one of the least reliable ways to automate Word. Please tell us what task you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just edited my post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A series of keystrokes aren't necessary, just better use of Word's Find and Replace utility. Here are the steps:

1. In Word, choose **Edit>Find>Advanced Find and Replace**.
2. Click on the **Replace** tab.
3. Click on the **down-pointing arrowhead** button to expand the dialog.
4. Check the **Use wildcards** option
5. In *Find what*, enter this regex: **([0-9]{3})**. This will find three digits in a row.
6. Click in the *Replace with* field and type **\1^p**. This copies the found number and adds a return after it.
7. Click on the **Format button** at the bottom of the dialog and choose **Style**.
8. Select your custom style.
9. Click on **Replace All**.